# Delete object consisting of multiple tkinter widgets

Tags: python, tkinter

In my program, I have an object `startscreencanvas`. It consists of a canvas, labels widgets and buttons. I want to delete the object including all of its widgets. How can I do this? Please help!

The code:

```
class createcanvas:
    def __init__(self, master, title, button1text, button1command, button2text, button2command, screen):
        master.canvas = Canvas(root, width=610, height=610, bg='#82f2ff', borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0)
        master.canvas.pack()
        #   
        self.titlelabel = Label(master.canvas, image=photo1)
        self.titlelabel.place(x=0, y=100, width=600, height=100)
        #
        self.button1 = Button(master.canvas, text=button1text, command=button1command, relief = 'groove', font=("Ariel", 30))
        self.button1.place(x=100, y=450)
        #
        self.button2 = Button(master.canvas, text=button2text, command=button2command, relief = 'groove', font=("Ariel", 30))
        self.button2.place(x=350, y=450)
        #
        if screen == 'loginscreen':
            usernamelabel = Label(master.canvas, image=photo2, relief = 'flat')
            usernamelabel.place(x=95, y=250, width=175, height=50)
            #
            global usernameentry
            usernameentry = Entry(master.canvas, relief = 'groove',  font=("Ariel", 30))
            usernameentry.place(x=275, y=250, width=200, height=50)
            #
            passwordlabel = Label(master.canvas, image=photo3, relief = 'flat')
            passwordlabel.place(x=95, y=300, width=175, height=50)
            #
            global passwordentry
            passwordentry = Entry(master.canvas, relief = 'groove', show="*", font=("Ariel", 30))
            passwordentry.place(x=275, y=300, width=200, height=50)



def startscreen():
    global startscreencanvas
    startscreencanvas = createcanvas(root, 'Maths revision program', "Login", login,
                                     "Register", register, "loginscreen")

startscreen()
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2):

If you make `createcanvas` a subclass of a tkinter widget (eg: `Canvas`), destroying the instance will destroy all child widgets.

Otherwise, you need to change your code so that you can call the `destroy` method of the internal canvas. Since all of the other widgets are children of the canvas, when you delete the canvas, the child widgets will be automatically destroyed.